# How to Approve more than one request using nintex workflow using Custom C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2016, nintex-workflow

- we develop  custom web part to display my tasks using Nintex Workflow
- my tasks appear in list view using C#
- we want to add checkbox field in list view to check in  tasks that i want  to approve the tasks at once by one button click .

how to develop it using c# or is there nintex library to facilitate that  ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, since it is called **list view**. You can only view it, if you want to change any data there, you need to open it first(manually), but you can use flexitask or approval task for approval (can send by email) from Nintex Workflow.